# Is using popen() in C/C++ is a bad coding practise?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, timezone

I want to change the timezone for Linux system. I know there are many ways.
One way is to use **tzset()** function and another is to call '**timedatectl**' command from 'popen()' function.
I am using second approach i.e, using "**popen()**".

I just want to ask **is it a good programming practice to use "popen()" in your code?**

Also, I am carefully calling "pclose()" for every "popen()".

Comment: It's C or C++, pick one please.

Comment: If there is a function call to do the job I would prefer using it above spawning a new process, if not there is nothing wrong with using `popen`. Error handling using function calls is often easier and if a function call is missing or wrong you will most likely get a compile time error. IMO: It's not always bad practice but in your special case it is.

Comment: Asking a Question like that means that you tried already something and you found out that something went wrong or could go wrong . If it is so, what exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: its not bad practice to use popen unless until you are aware what you want to achieve. I have seen the code where some used popen to cat the file and search a string in it. This can be achieved just by using file read and search for the string.

Comment: In general using popen when you have a direct function that does the same job is worst because you use more resources and probably it runs much slower.

Comment: @GillBates Do you think the answer would be different for C++ as opposed to C? Does C++ have a better `popen()` in itst standard library?

Comment: @Michi well, for changing time zone, using 'tzset()' i  executed program successfully but, 'timezone' is not changed actually. But, if I do the same using 'popen()' it's working. But, I was not sure whether it's good/bad from a coding perspective.

Comment: To be more C++y you could use [Boost.Process](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html).

Comment: @HenriMenke I am using c++ 98.

Comment: @sonugupta I see you do not know what [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_(C%2B%2B_libraries)) is.  You have a lot to learn about C++ and to catch up on.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I am on my way to learn boost. But, I am working on a product which uses C++ 98.

Comment: @sonugupta What makes you think Boost does not work with C++98?

Comment: @HenriMenke Ahh, it's not like that. My organization is not allowing me to use Boost. That's it. I have some restrictions. But I have started to learn boost for widening my horizon of knowledge. :)

Comment: Tzset only sets the timezone for the calling process and its descendants. It's not permanent. You can also set the TZ variable in your shell init files, but that affects only one user. Timedatectl changes the time zone for the entire system, and you may need to supply an administrator password. Can you explain what you need to do?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  Consider I am having server-client application. Location of clients is changing. Server tracks the location of clients. Based on location, it will explicitly tell client to change there timezone.

Answer (score 0):

`popen()` invokes a shell to run the command which is an extra unnecessary layer of indirection. Plus there are all sorts of security pitfalls, for instance, you don't have control over the environment - or which shell actually gets invoked.

I'd say it's fine for prototypes and proofs of concept, but for production code you should use `fork()`, one of the execs and pipes for IO.

**EDIT**

If there is a function equivalent to doinf something by invoking a command, always use that first. For example, if you can achieve what you want with `tzset()`, always use that in preference to spawning a new process.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you are saying to do this for production code. 
'pid_t pID = fork();
if(pID == 0)
{

 //popen() stuff
 
}'

Comment: It's a lot more complicated. You have to create pipes for stdin and stdout, then you fork, then you replace stdin and stdout in the child with the pipes and exec. The parent has to put what's needed on stdin and read what's needed from stdout and then wait for the child to exit and read its exit status.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong about `popen` in general, if you really need a child process to do a specific job for you.

`popen` creates a pipe allowing you to either read the output (what it wrote to stdout) of the child process or write input to its stdin - but not both at the same time.

If you are not interested in either option, you possibly might prefer calling [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) instead (however, `system` will wait for the process to terminate, in contrast to popen - pclose waits for).

But why would you want to create a separate process, if you can do the same job by simply calling an ordinary function (system call or not)? You are creating a lot of overhead using a process then (process must be initialised and hooked into OS, it needs its own memory for executable code, heap and stack, ...)!

It gets a little more complicated, if the job in question requires a considerable amount of time and you cannot afford to wait for the function to complete, but *need* to do some other stuff. However, in such a case, I'd rather create a *thread* only and again call the function from there...

Comment: I agree. But what I think is if my task is 'small' and can be done using 'popen()' quickly with less number of the code. Why I should waste my time in writing long and complex code. At the end, it's giving me the same output. Obviously, my perspective may be wrong. Any guidance?

Comment: @sonugupta Well, difference between quick and dirty and production code... If you need some "use once and throw it away afterwards" tool just for yourself, you *can* spare your time... If you are writing productive code - do it properly!

Comment: @sonugupta (I personally prefer writing proper code even for my own personal use tools, though...)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I will definitely follow same practice.